# How do I make an Oracle SQL query in APEX javascript, and store it in a variable?

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I made a dynamic action in apex, of type *Execute javascript code*. Now I need to create a query (**with javascript code**) like

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition
```

and store the result in a variable. I expect the result to be a string and store it in a variable.

I can't find a way to do this in the Internet. Probably I do not know the right wording because I have zero experience in javascript.

I guess there is a specific javascript or Apex API function call to do a query (What is the function name?)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Execute PL/SQL code option instead and put PL/SQL code there.

```
begin
  select column_name into variable_name 
from table 
where condition;

end;
```

You migh use declare statement if varable was not known before.

Comment: I need to use javascript, because I need the result in javascript variable